# Angular 6 Event.Prevent default for radio button

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

In Angular How can we prevent click event of radio button based on condition.

Please check below link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yrvzcl?file=src/app/app.component.ts

I want to prevent change event if total is zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could put `(click)="changeEve($event)"`
And then inside `changeEve` function call `event.preventDefault()` based on your condition.

Thing is `(change)` event occurs after click has been handled. The actual prevention of the default radio-button behavior should happen on `(click)` event.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-emeosp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html